# Мир начинает сильно лагать после почти полной генерации. Unity Procedural Terrain

Tags: unity3d, mesh, procedural-generation

У меня есть процедурный ландшафт. Есть тайлы (чанки) и есть объект Terrain, который при подходе к краю ландшафта генерирует через Coroutine из-за того что  сильные просады фпс когда тайлы генерируются. Как это чинить?

Слева сверху координаты x/y/z и fps.

Гиф: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMWeP.jpg

Вот Скрипт который ставит чанки:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

class _Chunk
{
    public GameObject theChunk;
    public float creationTime;

    public _Chunk(GameObject t, float ct)
    {
        theChunk = t;
        creationTime = ct;
    }
}

public class WorldProcedural : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject chunk;
    public GameObject player;

    public int ChunkSize = 16;
    public int halfTilesX = 16;
    public int halfTilesZ = 16;

    Vector3 startPos;
    Hashtable chunks = new Hashtable();

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        halfTilesX = ESCManager.DrawDistance;
        halfTilesZ = ESCManager.DrawDistance;

        StartCoroutine(UpdateWorld());
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

        this.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        startPos = Vector3.zero;

        float updateTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

        for (int x = -halfTilesX; x < halfTilesX; x++)
        {
            for (int z = -halfTilesZ; z < halfTilesZ; z++)
            {
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3((x * ChunkSize + startPos.x), 0, (z * ChunkSize + startPos.z));
                GameObject t = (GameObject)Instantiate(this.chunk, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                t.transform.SetParent(transform);

                string tilename = "Chunk_" + ((int)(pos.x)).ToString() +
                    "_" + ((int)(pos.z)).ToString();
                t.name = tilename;
                _Chunk chunk = new _Chunk(t, updateTime);
                chunks.Add(tilename, chunk);
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator UpdateWorld()
    {
        int xMove = (int)(player.transform.position.x - startPos.x);
        int ZMove = (int)(player.transform.position.z - startPos.z);

        if (Mathf.Abs(xMove) >= ChunkSize || Mathf.Abs(ZMove) >= ChunkSize)
        {
            float updateTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

            int playerX = (int)(Mathf.Floor(player.transform.position.x / ChunkSize) * ChunkSize);
            int playerZ = (int)(Mathf.Floor(player.transform.position.z / ChunkSize) * ChunkSize);

            for (int x = -halfTilesX; x < halfTilesX; x++)
            {
                for (int z = -halfTilesZ; z < halfTilesZ; z++)
                {
                    Vector3 pos = new Vector3((x * ChunkSize + playerX), 0, (z * ChunkSize + playerZ));

                    string tilename = "Chunk_" + ((int)(pos.x)).ToString() +
                        "_" + ((int)(pos.z)).ToString();

                    if (!chunks.ContainsKey(tilename))
                    {
                        GameObject t = (GameObject)Instantiate(this.chunk, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                        t.transform.SetParent(transform);
                        t.name = tilename;
                        _Chunk chunk = new _Chunk(t, updateTime);
                        chunks.Add(tilename, chunk);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (chunks[tilename] as _Chunk).creationTime = updateTime;
                    }


                }
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            }

            Hashtable newTerrain = new Hashtable();
            foreach (_Chunk chk in chunks.Values)
            {
                if (chk.creationTime != updateTime)
                {
                    Destroy(chk.theChunk);
                }
                else
                {
                    newTerrain.Add(chk.theChunk.name, chk);
                }
            }

            chunks = newTerrain;
            startPos = player.transform.position;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Смотрите в `Profiler`.

Comment: @Yaroslav лагают скрипты.

Comment: Еще бы они не лагали, вы каждый фрейм создаете корутину, которая живет дольше одного кадра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое страшное, что ты каждый FixedUpdate запускаешь корутину.
Пока предыдущая еще даже не отработала до конца скорее всего, ты запускаешь новую и так делее. В корутине ты проходишь по всем тайлам циклом со вложенным циклом, потом ждешь пол секунды, потом все повторяется заного (скорее всего). Потом удивляешься , что все тормозит.

Попробуй вызывать yield return null каждые n итераций.

```
int everyNthIteration = 10; // будешь каждую десятую итерацию пропускать кадр    

for (int x = -halfTilesX; x < halfTilesX; x++)
{
    for (int z = -halfTilesZ; z < halfTilesZ; z++)
    {
         if(z % everyNthIteration == 0)
         {
             yield return null; // то, что ты там по пол секунды ждешь, 
                                // а потом молотишь по новой на твоим
                                //  тормозам никак не поможет
         }
```

Это во-первых.
Во вторых,
Вместо

```
if (!chunks.ContainsKey(tilename))
 {
 }
 else
 {
     chunks[tilename] blah blah
 }
```

делай так

```
if (!chunks.TryGetValue(tilename, out var chunk))
{
}
else
{
    тут уже делаешь с 'chunk' что тебе надо // 
}
```

Не делай в цикле так со строками:

```
string tilename = "Chunk_" + ((int)(pos.x)).ToString() +
                    "_" + ((int)(pos.z)).ToString();
```

Надо хотя-бы так:
    string tilename = $"Chunk_{(int)pos.x}_{(int)pos.z}"; //или используй string.Format.. если пишешь куда-то циклом то тогда вообще stringbuilder надо использовать. Это для того, чтобы не др*чить зря твой сборщик мусора.

Ну и на последок, transform.SetParent() и Destroy() тебе тоже много вызовов GC дают. Подумай можно ли без этого обойтись в циклах. Между n вызовов Destroy можно было бы тоже пропускать кадр. Тут уж смотри с какой 'скоростью' тебе надо обновлять мир.

Comment: И ещё, зачем ты каждый раз HashTable новый создаёшь? Не дешевле обновить старый?